# Rewrite all Subdomains to Main Domain on APACHE with .htacces without Wildcards

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite all Subdomains to main Domain with .htaccess. I found this [Redirect any sub domain to a page on main domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730298/redirect-any-sub-domain-to-a-page-on-main-domain), but does not work.

**Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.**

I tried other ways also, but when I type some random subdomain sub.domain.com, then I see always this error.

Then I watched this Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoVcEqnqqbI and he makes same thing, what I need, but he has Wildacard Subdomains. I have not with my hosting Package Wildcard Subdomains. This is Apache Server with PHP 7.0.

**Is there any way to do this without WIldarcards?**

P.S. I need to rewrite and not Redirect. If User types sub.domain.com must stay on it, but see content same as on domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS only matters in so far as your subdomains must point *somewhere* that can redirect them; `.htaccess` can't replace that. If you want to be able to type *any* subdomain, and go to the one place, you need wildcard DNS.

Hopefully you don't mean exactly the same content for every subdomain, that's not good for SEO.

Comment: yea, I have now Wildcard subdomains, without this, I could not do something like this. Thanks.