# Catch random subdomain with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like to access my index.php  file from any subdomain

example:

anything.mywebsite.com >>> index.php

Is it possible to do that with just a htaccess ?

Comment: You don't use .htaccess for that.  It's solved via your virtual host configuration.  If using Apache you just create several ServerAlias entries for the given VHost

Comment: Here are similar questions
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730298
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388618

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in your virtual host configuration.  Example for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName something.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias anything.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias anything-else.mywebsite.com

    ...other VHost settings...
</VirtualHost>
```